# CSS to put a character between two HTML tags only if there is something in both

Tags: html, css

I've got two values in my Model where either or both can contain a value.   If both contain a value, I want to put a dash between them in the View. So, using span tags as containers for the properties, the output HTML will be

```
<span>First</span><span></span>
<span></span><span>Second</span>
<span>First</span>-<span>Second</span>
```

I can ViewModel this but I wanted to know if it was possible using just HTML/CSS.   I've tried using the `before` and `after` CSS commands to insert the dash, but it doesn't do the job.

Any ideas if it's possible and if so, how?

Comment: Sounds like a job for JS?

Comment: Interesting question 

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CSS doesn't support inserting generated content before or after an element, so a pure solution to this isn't going to be straightforward.

If your spans need to be inline, or if you can't modify your HTML (e.g. the dash *must* appear *between* the two spans), you're better off handing this logic over to either JavaScript or the view model (or I guess both, if you're using a JavaScript MVVM framework).

If not, and you don't mind cheating a little and/or utterly trashing the semantics of your HTML, placing the dash in a third span following the first two allows you to show it using `span:not(:empty) + span:not(:empty) + span` and hide it otherwise.

Or, depending on how your layout works, you may be able to cheat in other ways. For example, if putting the dash *in* one of your spans is an option (e.g. because the spans don't have any special formatting), it's as easy as

```
span:not(:empty) + span:not(:empty)::before { content: '-'; }
```

Whichever it is, though, I suspect you'll invariably have an easier time just exposing a separate property in your view model.

Answer (score 2):

So here it is a quick tricky way with just html & css complex selectors.

- The base here is to include the dash `-` on the second element if it is not empty.
- And if the first element is empty then push the second to offset and hide the dash.

```css
div {
  overflow: hidden;
  line-height: 2em;
}

div span:first-child:empty {
  margin-left: -10px;
}

div span:last-child:not(:empty):before {
  content: "-";
  width: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div><span>First</span><span></span></div>
<div><span></span><span>Second</span></div>
<div><span>First</span><span>Second</span></div>
```

---

Using the `+` adjacent selector will be like:

```css
div {
  overflow: hidden;
  line-height: 2em;
}

div span:first-child:not(:empty) + span:not(:empty):before {
  content: "-";
  width: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div><span>First</span><span></span></div>
<div><span></span><span>Second</span></div>
<div><span>First</span><span>Second</span></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible, though I think there are probably better ways to do it, like at the time the data is added.

Here's my solution.

```css
span:nth-child(odd):not(:empty)+span:nth-child(even):not(:empty)::before {
  content: '-'
}
```

```html
<span>First</span><span></span>
<span></span><span>Second</span>
<span>First</span><span>Second</span>

<br><br>
<span>First</span><span></span><br>
<span></span><span>Second</span><br>
<span>First</span><span>Second</span>
```

What I'm saying is whenever there is an odd position span that is not empty it will update the next even position span if it's not empty with a hyphen.

I hope you find this helpful

Answer (score 0):

```
In CSS, ::after creates a pseudo-element that is the last child of the selected element. It is often used to add cosmetic content to an element with the content property. It is inline by default.

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.hypen-text::after {
   content: "-";
}
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<span>first</span>
<span>second</span>
<span class="hypen-text">first</span><span>second</span>

</body>
</html>

if you have still doubt refer this link https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::after
```

Answer (score 0):

I used @Boltclock's answer

```
span:not(:empty) + span:not(:empty)::before { content: '-'; }
```

which made it surprisingly easy (when you know how) and just added classes to the spans so I can make sure it only happens where I need it to and so I can follow what's happening a bit more easily when I come back to this in a week's time :) The HTML I used is

```
<span class="spnAddADash">
    <span class="spnValueOne">First</span>
    <span class="spnValueTwo">Second</span>
</span>
```

And the corresponding style is

```
.spnAddADash .spnValueOne:not(:empty) + .spnValueTwo:not(:empty)::before {
    content: '- '; 
}
```

which both together render

```
First
Second
First - Second
```